# Memory Error when trying to fit a classifier

Tags: python, pandas, memory, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working on a classification task and my training file is a csv which has about 8GB(approx. 7.2 million lines and 212 columns). Firstly, my approach was to put all this csv file in a pandas dataframe and then use it as multidimensional array, to train my naïve Bayes classifier, but when I tried to fit the data I got a `memory error` ( I am working on a machine with 8GB of ram and a 64 bit version of Python).

After that, I tried to split my `dataframe` in 5 pieces and use the `partia_fit()` method, but I still run out of memory.

This is my code so far (the target values are extracted from other txt file):

```
from csv import DictReader
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import numpy
from pandas import*


target_values_train = []

with open('train.txt') as f:
    reader = DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        target_values_train.append(int(row['human-generated']))

y_train = numpy.asarray(target_values_train)
y_train = y_train[:, numpy.newaxis]

tp = read_csv('train-indices.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000, delimiter=';', skiprows=1)
df_train = concat(tp, ignore_index=True)
del df_train['id']
print(df_train)
print(df_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
df1, df2, df3, df4 = np.array_split(df_train, 5)
y1, y2, y3, y4, y5=np.array_split(y_train, 5)
print(df1.shape)
print(df2.shape)
print(df3.shape)


clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.partial_fit(df1, y1)
clf.partial_fit(df2, y2)
clf.partial_fit(df3, y3)
clf.partial_fit(df4, y4)
clf.partial_fit(df5, y5)
```

Any suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: Why not put everything in a loop and only store and read the required lines for each partial_fit?

Comment: Do you really need to train on all of this data? If data is homogeneus enouth, you can train on the part of data which fit memory and produce a good score. Try it. If it's will not enougth, you can train and predict on all parts on training data, then simply avarege predictions and get even better result.

Comment: And you can try to del any unneeded data right after usage.

Comment: Yes, I think I will try to predict on all parts on training data and after that I will average predictions. Trank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Using `pd.concat` you are reloading all the data once again in memory, so it's equivalent to loading the file all at once.

You need to train by iterating over the chunks one by one. For example, you would do the following:

```
tp = read_csv('training_data.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=1000, delimiter=';', skiprows=1)
clf = MultinomialNB()
for chunk in tp:
    clf.partial_fit(chunk[["train_col1", "train_col1",...]], chunk["y1"])
```